# Modify Json data to create new object by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have a json data as following

```
{
  "file1": {
    "function1": {
      "calls": {
        "439:0": [
          "441:24"
        ],
        "441:24": [
          "443:4"
        ],
        "443:4": [
          "447:7",
          "445:10"
        ],
        "445:10": [
          "449:4"
        ],
        "447:7": [
          "449:4"
        ]
      }
    },
    "function2": {
      "calls": {
        "391:0": [
          "393:8"
        ],
        "393:8": [
          "397:7"
        ],
        "397:7": [
          "395:27"
        ]
      }
    },
    "function3": {
      "calls": null
    },
    "function4": {
      "calls": null
    }
  },
  "file2": {
    "function5": {
      "calls": null
    },
    "function6": {
      "calls": {
        "391:0": [
          "393:8"
        ],
        "393:8": [
          "397:7"
        ],
        "397:7": [
          "395:27"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need to convert it following format for "function1"

```
    {
  "nodes": [
    {
      "id": "439:0",
      "line": "439:0"
    },
    {
      "id": "441:24",
      "line": "441:24"
    },
    {
      "id": "443:4",
      "line": "443:4"
    },
    {
      "id": "447:7",
      "line": "447:7"
    },
    {
      "id": "445:10",
      "line": "445:10"
    },
    {
      "id": "449:4",
      "line": "449:4"
    }
  ],
  "links": [
    {
      "source": "439:0",
      "target": "441:24"
    },
    {
      "source": "441:24",
      "target": "443:4"
    },
    {
      "source": "443:4",
      "target": "447:7"
    },
    {
      "source": "443:4",
      "target": "445:10"
    },
    {
      "source": "445:10",
      "target": "449:4"
    },
    {
      "source": "447:7",
      "target": "449:4"
    }
  ]
}
```

Where the "call" keys are line and id in "nodes" and source in "links". Targets are the values inside calls. If any key has multiple values than for each value it will create a source-target pair.

This will be used later as  `data.nodes.map(function(d){return d.line})`

I have tried the following code but its not working properly. Its giving an array with correct information but the way i need to use it in further steps, its not working there. Its giving errors like `Property 'nodes' does not exist on type 'any[]'`.

```
let res = {}
let nodes = []
let links = []
Object.entries(input0).map(([fileName, fileObject]) => {
  Object.entries(fileObject).map(([functionName, functionObject]) => {
    if(functionName=="function1"){
      Object.entries(functionObject).map(([functionKey, functionValue]) => { 
        if(functionKey === "calls") {
          if(functionValue != null){
            Object.entries(functionValue).map(([callKey, callObject]) => {     
              nodes = [...nodes,{"id": callKey, "line": callKey}] 
              callObject.forEach(x => {
                links = [...links,{"source": callKey, "target": x}] 
              });
              res = {"nodes": nodes, "links": links} //nodes.concat(links)
            })                     
          }
        }
      })
    }
  })
})
console.log(res)
```

Someone please help. Thank you for your time.

Comment: does the given data match the wanted result? where do you get the key/values from?

Comment: I tried to build it as the wanted format with nodes and links. My current result has the information but not in correct way. Its asking for object and mine is in array.

Comment: I'm not seeing a clear connection between your *input* and *output*. For example `191` is in your *output* but not your *input*. Can you provide a description of the algorithm you wish to implement?

Comment: I have updated the target data.

Answer (score 1):

You could omit unwanted properies and head for nested once and build a new set of nodes by checking existent nodes and assign all links without further checking.

```js
function getNodesLinks(object, result = { nodes: [], links: [] }) {
    if (object.calls === null) return result;
    if (!object.calls) {
        Object.values(object).forEach(v => getNodesLinks(v, result));
        return result;
    }
    Object.entries(object.calls).forEach(([source, targets]) => {
        if (!result.nodes.some(({ id }) => id === source)) {
            result.nodes.push({ id: source, line: source });
        }
        targets.forEach(target => {
            if (!result.nodes.some(({ id }) => id === target)) {
                result.nodes.push({ id: target, line: target });
            }
            result.links.push({ source, target });
        });
    });
    return result;
}

var data = { file1: { function1: { calls: { "439:0": ["441:24"], "441:24": ["443:4"], "443:4": ["447:7", "445:10"], "445:10": ["449:4"], "447:7": ["449:4"] } }, function2: { calls: { "391:0": ["393:8"], "393:8": ["397:7"], "397:7": ["395:27"] } }, function3: { calls: null }, function4: { calls: null } }, file2: { function5: { calls: null }, function6: { calls: { "391:0": ["393:8"], "393:8": ["397:7"], "397:7": ["395:27"] } } } },
    result = getNodesLinks(data);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Its giving error as "Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'unknown'" in targets.forEach(target => { ..... line!

Comment: what type of targets do you have?

Comment: does it works here with stack snippets? please add the exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this ,this should be working fine.

```
           var res = {};
            var nodes = [];
            var Links = [];
            var json = '{"file1":{"function1":{"calls":{"439:0":["441:24"],"441:24":["443:4"],"443:4":["447:7","445:10"],"445:10":["449:4"],"447:7":["449:4"]}},"function2":{"calls":{"391:0":["393:8"],"393:8":["397:7"],"397:7":["395:27"]}},"function3":{"calls":null},"function4":{"calls":null}},"file2":{"function5":{"calls":null},"function6":{"calls":{"391:0":["393:8"],"393:8":["397:7"],"397:7":["395:27"]}}}}';
            var jsonObj = JSON.parse(json);
            if ("function1" in jsonObj.file1) {
                if ('calls' in jsonObj.file1.function1) {
                    for (var i = 0; Object.keys(jsonObj.file1.function1.calls).length > i; i++) {
                        nodes.push({ "id": Object.keys(jsonObj.file1.function1.calls)[i], "line": Object.keys(jsonObj.file1.function1.calls)[i] });
                            for (var j = 0; Object.values(jsonObj.file1.function1.calls)[i].length > j; j++) {
                                Links.push({ "source": Object.keys(jsonObj.file1.function1.calls)[i], "target": Object.values(jsonObj.file1.function1.calls)[i][j] });
                        }
                    }
                    res = { "nodes": nodes, "links": Links }
                    console.log(res);
                }
            }
```